# Binary Classification Problem: How to Proceed With Severe Data Imbalance?

Tags: machine-learning, imbalanced-data

##### The Problem

After pre-processing a raw dataset, I obtained a clean but severely imbalanced dataset with 341 observations with label `1` and 3 observations with label `0` (more details about the dataset at the bottom).

```
    Dataset shape:  (344, 1500)
    Dataset class label distribution:  Counter({1: 341, 0: 3})
```

What can I do to proceed with this dataset for classification?

What I have tried:

1. Split the dataset into train-test sets with 70:30 ratio with stratify on class label

```
    Train data shape:  (240, 1500) 
    Train data class label distribution: Counter({1: 238, 0: 2})

    Test data shape:  (104, 1500) 
    Test data class label distribution: Counter({1: 103, 0: 1})
```

2. Perform oversampling on train data using SMOTE (synthetic minority oversampling technique) with `k_neighbour` set to 1

```
    After SMOTE:

    Train data shape:  (476, 1500)
    Train data class label distribution: Counter({1: 238, 0: 238})
```

I plan to train a classifier using the oversampled train data and use the test data to get the classification result.

But does this make sense? In my opinion it does not make sense since

1. The **oversampled train data** might **overfit** the model because the oversampled train data now has many observations with class label `0` which are oversampled based on only 2 observations.
2. The minority class label of the **test data** only have 1 observation out of 104 samples. Therefore the classifier will have high accuracy by just making prediction on the majority class label (Initially I plan to perform SMOTE on test data too but I read from somewhere that oversampling techniques are only used on train data).

I am really stuck here and I could not find any relevant information for this problem.

---

##### A brief summary of the acquired mulit-omics dataset:

The raw lung cancer (LUSC) dataset was obtained from http://acgt.cs.tau.ac.il/multi_omic_benchmark/download.html. It consists of 3 omics data types with 1 clinical dataset. The 3 omics data types consists of 3 different omics expressions (gene expression, DNA methylation & miRNA expression) while the clinical dataset consists of the binary class label `sample_type` (along with other unimportant attributes) for the 3 omics data types.

The aim is to obtain a multi-omics dataset by combining the 3 omics data types.
To obtain the multi-omics data, the 3 omics data types were concatenated with the clinical data (with `sample_type` as the class label) based on `sampleID` in all 4 datasets. The end product is a severely imbalaned dataset which consists of 344 observations with 341 observations with `Primary Tumour` label (has cancer, referred as `1`) and 3 observations with `Solid Tissue Normal` label (no cancer, referred as `0`)

Comment: "How to deal with unblanced data" is too broad of a question. It also doesn't have anything to do with Python. Consider researching the topic a bit more, there are multiple approaches to the problem and no universal one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a statistics question. In my opinion, you should not try to estimate anything on these data. You do not know what sets the 0's apart. Just to make a simple logistic regression, I'd recommend having at least 30-40 observations (ideally more).

The simplest estimator based on your data would be to guess 1 every time. That would lead to 99 percent accuracy, you can't expect to beat that with any complex models.

Comment: Accuracy isnt helping here as a metric. Depending on what the goal is, it might be better to stick to precision, recall, f1 or auc to compare different models

Comment: In general, I agree. But in the example, there are no 0 predictions. Therefore precision=accuracy and recall is 1 and the extra metrics do not add any new information

Comment: you are right sorry didn't read the post properly enough